# Magento 2.3, patch PRODSECBUG-2198-2.3-CE-2019

Tags: magento2.3

Having difficulty applying this patch using git apply, as returns missing directories because our magento was installed using composer, so does not have lib/internal/magento.

How can I apply this patch?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-patch.html

Comment: I am running with Magento 2.2.7 cloud, not able to apply this patch. its returns as "Skipped patch" with the file name

Answer (score 2):

Change the patch file paths to match with vendor paths.

Ex: for PRODSECBUG-2198-2.3-CE-2019,change path as;

> app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/ProductFrontendAction/Synchronizer.php

to

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/ProductFrontendAction/Synchronizer.php

**NOTE:** make sure to remove precedent "a/" and "b/" from the paths. Do the same for all file paths.

And execute the following command:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

If you didn't get hunk errors, check with the related files and observe the patch is applied correctly.

---

**UPDATE:**

You can download composer related Patch from below link, under title "Magento Open Source Patches - 2.x".
https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento

Ex:
PRODSECBUG-2198-2.3-CE.composer.patch

Comment: Thanks. great hints. :)