# magento2 apply patch prodsecbug issue found

Tags: magento2, patches

seems simple enough to aplly prodsecbug patch but I get this ...

```
public_html$ bash PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch
diff: unrecognized option '--git'
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.
PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch: line 2: index: command not found
PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch: line 3: ---: command not found
PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch: line 4: +++: command not found
PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch: line 5: @@: command not found
PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch: line 6: =: command not found
PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `$actions'
PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch: line 8: `         foreach ($actions as $action) {'
```

Comment: please go thorugh this "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267629/magento-2-3-patch-prodsecbug-2198-2-3-ce-2019/267734"

Answer (score 1):

Install the patch using this command

```
patch -p0 < PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch
```

If you get

> patch command not found error

install the patch command using either

`sudo apt-get install patch` or `sudo yum install patch`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nc3le9 error something like this

Comment: Remove the a and b before "vendor" in patch file. The file path is wrong this is what the error specifies